# How to remove Accept-char header from HTTP post request

Tags: java, http, sip, webservice-client, restful-architecture

I am using rest template for creating `HTTP post` request . But request contain by default added Accept-char header with huge Content . Please suggest how to exclude addition of that header. Below is the code i am using:

```
HttpHeader header= new HttpHeader();
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

header.setContentType("application/xml");

String body=" content of body ";

HttpEntity<string>  request=new HttpEntity<string> (body,header);

template.postForObject(URL,request,String.class);
```

Comment: Do you mean "Accept-Charset"? And what exactly would be "huge"???

Comment: Yes Accept-charset  I meant it's value and i dnt want this header in request .How can I remove this header ?

Answer (score 1):

This should remove 'Accept-Charset' header:

```
StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
stringHttpMessageConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, stringHttpMessageConverter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I have done this long time back with same solution :)